# debuild throws `extended-description-is-empty`

Tags: build, debian

I'm trying to build ddar(https://github.com/basak/ddar) from sources. These are the commands I issued:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts python-protobuf debhelper python-all-dev python-support xmltoman python-setuptools

git clone https://github.com/basak/ddar.git
debuild -i -us -uc -b
```

My goal is to install the ddar binary, but I can't figure out what is going wrong. Here are the last couple lines spit out by `debuild -i -us -uc -b`:

```
   dh_installdeb
   dh_gencontrol
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: Provides field of package ddar: unknown substitution variable ${python:Provides}
   dh_md5sums
   dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: warning: 'debian/ddar/DEBIAN/control' contains user-defined field 'Python-Version'
dpkg-deb: warning: ignoring 1 warning about the control file(s)

dpkg-deb: building package `ddar' in `../ddar_0.1-1_amd64.deb'.
 dpkg-genchanges -b >../ddar_0.1-1_amd64.changes
dpkg-genchanges: binary-only upload - not including any source code
 dpkg-source -i --after-build ddar
dpkg-buildpackage: binary only upload (no source included)
Now running lintian...
W: ddar: new-package-should-close-itp-bug
E: ddar: extended-description-is-empty
Finished running lintian.
```

First problem seems to be `E: ddar: extended-description-is-empty` and the second problem I face is that I have no clue how to install the package. The latter is probably caused by the fact that the build process wasn't entirely successful.

How can I get rid of the error and how can I subsequently install the package?

I'm building under a non-privileged user on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Comment: Apparently the package is built in the parent directory, not the current directory. SOLVED.

Answer (score 4):

When I got the error `extended-description-is-empty` error, it was caused by a one line description in the *debian/control* file. The description must be more than one line.  Other than the first line, all the lines must be indented with some white space so that they are considered to be part of the description.

A valid description in *debian/control* would be:

```
Description: this software does some work
  This is its extended description.
```